# Routing and tolls cost services with same parameters in response returns different trips

Tags: here-api

I'm trying here maps API and I'm using routing and tolls cost services. I noticed, that I use same parameters but get different trip responses. I see in routing response summary flags different. In routing response I don't find tollroad flag. With parameter `tollrad:-2`, I want avoid tollroad, but if no route can be found, this limitations condition is weakened. How can I fix this?

Routing

https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?apikey=&cost_optimize=1&tollVehicleType=3&vehicleNumberAxles=3&trailerNumberAxles=2&waypoint0=39.72793,-105.01245&waypoint1=41.09575,-104.84611&routeAttributes=sm&mode=fastest;truck;traffic:disabled;tollroad:-2

In response:

```
"summary": {
                "distance": 175632,
                "trafficTime": 7882,
                "baseTime": 7852,
                "flags": [
                    "dirtRoad",
                    "motorway",
                    "builtUpArea"
                ],
                "text": "The trip takes <span class=\"length\">176 km</span> and <span class=\"time\">2:11 h</span>.",
                "travelTime": 7852,
                "_type": "RouteSummaryType"
            }
```

Tolls cost

https://tce.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?app_id=&app_code=&cost_optimize=1&mode=fastest;truck;traffic:disabled;tollroad:-2&currency=USD&tollVehicleType=3&vehicleNumberAxles=3&trailerNumberAxles=2&representation=overview&waypoint0=39.72793,-105.01245&waypoint1=41.09575,-104.84611&routeAttributes=sm

In response:

```
"summary": {
                "distance": 157729,
                "trafficTime": 6548,
                "baseTime": 6541,
                "flags": [
                    "dirtRoad",
                    "tollroad",
                    "motorway",
                    "builtUpArea"
                ],
                "text": "The trip takes <span class=\"length\">158 km</span> and <span class=\"time\">1:49 h</span>.",
                "travelTime": 6541,
                "_type": "RouteSummaryType"
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

the search will weaken only if no route is available, try considering soft exclude instead of strict exclude. Also the difference here is "mode" that gets considered in toll cost API, which reducing the overall distance by excluding the tolls.

Try experimenting further results below :

> https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/fleet_telematics_api

Comment: thanks. this resource helped and will help me in the future

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Shruti Kuber from HERE! He noticed that I use in toll cost extension and routing services parameter cost_optimize. But this parameter isn't mentioned in routing service docs.